# Providing new props to all react-router routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have multiple routes and I want all of them to inherit props from my provider, the problem is that all these components that I want to receive the props have `<Route>` parents, and it doesn't let the props flow through:

`` <Layout>
<Route
    key={`other-${i}`}
    path={path}
    render={props => (
        <Component
            someProp={someProp}
            {...props}
        />
    )}
/>
... more routes ...
</Layout> ``

`<Layout />` works fine here because it doesn't provide props, only restructure the layout, but I want another parent that passes props to `<Component />`. I can make it work by putting this provider as the immediate parent of `<Component />` but the problem is I have multiple components and it would get clutterly to put it as a parent for every single case. So how do I add a provider that passes props to all components?